# Why is the automatic line break not working with flex display?

Tags: html, css

Good night, I am developing a project and I need that after the text "Malha Suprema - Judas" he should wrap the line for the text "ACERT" to go down, but for some reason the 
 n works. I use the flex display and when I press it for some reason my text "Acert" loses the css. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

```css
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300;500&display=swap");
    :root {
        --dark: #333;
        --lightDark: #444;
    }
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body{
        background: var(--dark);
        touch-action: none;
    }
    div.musicPhoto img{
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
    }
    .btnPlayer{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    div.btnPlayer .playerImg{
        font-size: 80px;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    div.btnPlayer .playerBtn{
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        background: transparent;
    }
    div.musicData{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    div.musicData p{
        font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    }
    div.musicData p:nth-child(1){
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    div.musicData p:nth-child(2){
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 33px;
        color: #ebebeb;
    }
    div.musicItem{
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 15px;
        background: var(--lightDark);
        width: 93%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 2% auto;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SpotCode</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="musicItem">
            <div class="musicPhoto">
                <img src="assets/images/3348986.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="musicData">
                <p>Malha Suprema - Judas</p>
                <p>ACERT</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btnPlayer">
                <button class="playerBtn">
                    <span class="playerImg">
                        <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>
                    </span>                 
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: flex-direction:column to musicData

Comment: OR     flex-wrap: wrap; to musicData